# Store a list of enums in flutter drift (sqflite) package

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, sqflite, drift

I hope you are well.

I have a little problem with my application, I'm using the [Drift](https://pub.dev/packages/drift) package for the database and I'm trying to figure out how I can insert an enumeration list in my database.

I have a table Etablissements, which contains a column that will be an enumeration list that represents the different levels available in this establishment:

```
@DataClassName('Establishment')
class Establishments extends Table {
  TextColumn get id => text().clientDefault(() => generateId())();

  BoolColumn get isConfigured => boolean().withDefault(const Constant(false))();

  TextColumn get slogan => text().nullable()();

  TextColumn get contact => text().references(Contacts, #id)();

  TextColumn get name => text()();

  TextColumn get admin => text()();

  TextColumn get cycles => text().map(const CyclesListConverter())();

  @override
  Set<Column>? get primaryKey => {id};
}
```

And based on the documentation of the plugin, using [Type Converter](https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/advanced-features/type_converters/) to store complex data in a column, I was able to create my converter that will allow me to serialize the enumeration list into a JSON string in order to be able to store more easily the enumeration list in a column (and conversely to transform the JSON string back into an enumeration list

```
class CyclesListConverter extends TypeConverter<List<Cycles>, String> {
  const CyclesListConverter();

  @override
  List<Cycles>? mapToDart(String? fromDb) {
    if (fromDb == null) return null;

    final data = json.decode(fromDb);

    final studyCycles = data['body'];

    return studyCycles;
  }

  @override
  String? mapToSql(List<Cycles>? value) {
    if (value == null) return null;

    return json.encode(value);
  }
}
```

but at the execution of my program, and when I try to insert the

I get the following error from the Drift package

```
[log] Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Cycles'
```

Can you help me to solve the problem and make me understand the cause of the error and what I am doing wrong?

My enumerations

```
enum Cycles { elementary, primary, secondary, secondaryTechnique }
```

Answer (score 1):

After some time of reflection, here is how I was able to solve the problem.
I extract the value from the enumeration to store it as a string in the database.
This value is then added to a list of strings.
Then this list is encoded in JSON

```
String? mapToSql(List<Cycles>? value) {
    if (value == null) return null;
    var data = <String>[];

    for (var v in value) {
      final strCycle = v.displayName();
      data.add(strCycle);
    }

    return json.encode(data);
  }
```

And to find the enumeration in Dart, I perform the inverse operation to the previous one

I retrieve the list of strings (which represents my enumerations).
For each string of this list, I convert it back to the corresponding enumeration

```
List<Cycles>? mapToDart(String? fromDb) {
    if (fromDb == null) return null;

    var studyCycles = <Cycles>[];

    final jsonData = json.decode(fromDb);

    final strData = jsonData['body'] as List<String>;

    for (var string in strData) {
      final enumCycle = Cycles.values.firstWhere((element) => element.toString() == 'Cycles.$string');
      studyCycles.add(enumCycle);
    }

    return studyCycles;
  }
```